# GUI stuck.(Java netbeans),

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I added a function in my GUI and it holds for forever.
It was working fine before.[image: The Picture Here is showing my stuck GUI]

```
public void setBalance(String username,double balance){

        Node current = headNode;

        while(current!=null)
        {
            if(current.username.equalsIgnoreCase(username))
            {
                current.setBalance(balance);

            }else{
                current=current.getNext();
             
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the function I wrote, and it just stuck there.

```
private void D_EnterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String username = accountUsername.getText();

        String password = accountPassword.getText();

        boolean flag = false;
       S_Balance=l.findBalance(username, password);
        Deposit_text.setVisible(true);
        num1 = S_Balance + Double.parseDouble(D_deposit_text.getText()) ;
        Deposit_text.setEditable(false);
        Deposit_text.setText("Previous Balance:"+Double.toString(S_Balance)+"\nNew Balance:"+Double.toString(num1));
        S_Balance = S_Balance + Double.parseDouble(D_deposit_text.getText());
        l.setBalance(username, S_Balance);
        this.N_Deposit++;
        D_deposit_text.setText("");
        if(S_Balance < 25)
        {
            Status.setVisible(true);
            Active_Status.setVisible(false);
            S_TextField.setText("Your Balance is less than $25");
            SmileyFace.setVisible(false);
            Smiley1.setVisible(true);
        }else{
            Status.setVisible(false);
            Active_Status.setVisible(true);
            S_WithDraw.setEnabled(true);
            S_TextField.setText("You are good to go!!!");
            SmileyFace.setVisible(true);
            Smiley1.setVisible(false);
            W_Enter.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

This is where it is called.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got stuck because when you are finding the username, you are not breaking the while loop (so it would run forever). You should do something like:

```
public void setBalance(String username,double balance){

    Node current = headNode;

    while(current!=null)
    {
        if(current.username.equalsIgnoreCase(username))
        {
            current.setBalance(balance);
            break; // this will break the loop

        }else{
            current=current.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```